# How to fully migrate a server to another (What to do with DNS offered by the new registrar)?

Tags: domain-name-system, migration

I have questions regarding how to fully migrate my website to another server. I purchased a new host with this new registrar. I have this temporary url or space that I can migrate my content to. This part is done. Everything works on the new server, website, database, and mail with the temporary address.

This is the part where I get lost. I have this new DNS provided by the new registrar. What do I do now? Do I update and replace the old one on the previous registrar cpanel? Is it how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two possible things to do, depending on how your domain's DNS is set up.

1) If your domain's authorative name server is operated by your DNS registrar, then you need to log in to their control panel and change your domain's A records to point to your new server.

2) If your domain's authorative name server is on the same server than your domains, then you need to update your domain's NS records to point to the new server. You also need to make sure that the A records in the DNS on your new server are properly set up. This alternative is not that common with basic domain setups.